# Can't ORDER BY a column in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to order by a field in a JPQL query declaration, and it seems like it should be really simple, but I keep getting a compiler error.

I'm trying to order by the UserClockDate column, which is a part of UserTime rows. But every time I try to compile I get the error:

> SEVERE: Error in named query: fetchIfUserIsClockedInWithUser
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   UserClockDate of: models.UserTime [SELECT ut FROM models.UserTime ut
>   WHERE USER_ID = :user ORDER BY ut.UserClockDate DESC]

If I just take out the ORDER BY it compiles fine.

Here's the relevant part of the class itself:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "fetchAllUserTimes", query = "SELECT ut FROM UserTime ut"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "fetchIfUserIsClockedInWithUser", query = "SELECT ut FROM UserTime ut WHERE USER_ID = :user ORDER BY ut.UserClockDate DESC") 
    })
@Entity
@Table(name = "userTime")
@Component
public class UserTime implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "UserTimeId")
    private int userTimeId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "UserClockIn")
    @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime userClockIn;

    @Column(name = "UserClockOut")
    @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
    public DateTime userClockOut;

    @Column(name = "UserClockDate")
    @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
    public DateTime userClockDate;
```

Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean where you try to order by a field that doesn't exist? *UserClockDate* ought to be *userClockDate*

Comment: To clarify, you should use the name of the field in the entity not the name of the column in the table.

Comment: You're right! I should have caught that, thank you! I was mistakenly trying to use column names instead of field names.

Answer (score 2):

JPQL works on entities, their mapped columns and associations. It doesn't work on tables and columns.

There is no `USER_ID` field in the `UserTime` entity. There is no `UserClockDate` in the `UserTime` entity.

The query should be

```
select ut from models.UserTime ut where ut.user = :user order by ut.userClockDate desc
```

Side note: all the fields os UserTime are part of UserTime. No need to repeat the `user` prefix everywhere. Why not name the fields `clockIn`, `clockOut`, `clockDate` instead?